# iOS 14 PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType Select More

Tags: privacy, ios14

I am using this third party library that presents photos in a little gallery view that allows users to pick one.

With iOS 14, if the user selects to grant the app partial access to photos, the following message results with a `Select More...` prompt **EVERY TIME** user gets to this view.

This is obviously annoying the users.

Is it possible to somehow skip asking for more photos if access type is limited, but still show those shared with the app?

```
[PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType:PHAssetMediaTypeImage options:allPhotosOptions];
```

Comment: PHPhotoLibraryPreventAutomaticLimitedAccessAlert